# How can I delete previous file and add a new file in dropbox in iOS?

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api, delete-file

I am saving a `example.txt` file in my dropbox. And when I added some text in that txt file, I want to to delete previous file from Dropbox and adding new file as same example.txt name. But its not happening.

This is the Upload file code :

```
NSString *text = @"Hello Word !!!!";
NSString *filename = @"working-draft.txt";
NSString *localDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *localPath = [localDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
[text writeToFile:localPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


[self.restClient deletePath:@"/working-draft.txt"]; // Here I am deleting Previous txt file and adding new file

// Upload file to Dropbox
NSString *destDir = @"/";
[self.restClient uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
```

Delegate Method :

```
#pragma mark Delegate method for Uploading file in dropbox --------

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadedFile:(NSString *)destPath
          from:(NSString *)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully to path: %@", metadata.path);
self.activityIndicate.hidden = YES;

}
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"File upload failed with error: %@", error);
}
```

During Upload I deleted previous txt file and uploading a new file. But sometimes first its adding second file named as `example(2).txt` and after adding, its deleting the previous file.

How can I resolve this . Please anybody can help me. ?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You're not actually waiting for the delete to finish before uploading. You should wait until your `deletedPath` delegate is called (signifying that the delete is finished) before you try to add the file again.
2. If all you want to do is replace the file, there's no need to delete it first. You can just use the `overwrite` parameter.

Support for `overwrite` isn't great in the v1 iOS SDK, so I believe you need to use the overload of `uploadFile` that takes a `params` dictionary, like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@"true"
                                        forKey:@"overwrite"];
[self.restClient uploadFile:filename
                     toPath:destDir
                   fromPath:localPath
                     params:params];
```

Comment: params:params are not taking . This parameter is not available in restclient delegate method ?

Comment: @SRNayak Oh, sorry. It looks like that method isn't exposed via `DBRestClient.h`. Maybe just add a declaration there? Better yet, keep track of the `rev` of the file and pass it via `withParentRev` with the method you're already using. This is a safer way to overwrite just the version of the file you meant to.

Comment: Can u give some pinch of code according to my code. :)

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.

If you want to overwrite the file:

```
client.files.upload(path: filePath, mode: .overwrite, autorename: false, clientModified: nil, mute: true, input: data).response(completionHandler: { (response, error) in
    if let metadata = response {
      aPrint("Uploaded file name: \(metadata.name)"); aPrint("Uploaded file revision: \(metadata.rev)")
      completionHandler(metadata, error)

    } else {
      completionHandler(nil, error)
    }

  })
```

If you want to delete the file:

```
if let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient {
  client.files.delete(path: filePath).response(completionHandler: { (response, error) in
    if let metadata = response {
      aPrint("Uploaded file name: \(metadata.name)")
      completionHandler(metadata, error)
    }  else {
      completionHandler(nil, error)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I am not using Obj-C any more so I do not have it :(